# JWT Validation on separate web Api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, jwt

I have a core 3.1 web api is Vur.js client and it uses JWT token for security. This all works fine. I now have to add a second web api to the solution. My question is when the client accesses the second web api and send the token, that it received from the first, how would I validate that token? I really don't want to build a authentication server.

To answer Chetan Ranpariya

```
try {
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
    tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

    var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;
    var accountId = int.Parse(jwtToken.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "id").Value);

    // attach account to context on successful jwt validation
    context.Items["Account"] = await dataContext.Accounts.FindAsync(accountId);
}
```

Comment: How does the first web app validate the token?

Comment: Why can't you use this method in the second API?

Comment: I guess that I could but I would need a way to get the client's "Secret" to the second API. each Client has their own secret that is generated when they authenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is when the client accesses the second web api and send
> the token, that it received from the first, how would I validate that
> token?

In the second WebAPI application, you could refer the following steps to validate the JWT Token:

1. Add nuget package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer"
2. Add following namespaces in Startup.cs file

   ```
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;    
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;    
    using System.Text;
   ```
3. Create a new function in Startup class to register JWT service & then call this function in 'ConfigureServices' method. We are telling framework how to check if a request is authorized or not.

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        SetupJWTServices(services);
        services.AddControllers();
    }
    private void SetupJWTServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string key = "ThisismySecretKey"; //this should be same which is used while creating token      
        var issuer = "Test.com";  //this should be same which is used while creating token  

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddJwtBearer(options =>
      {
          options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
          {
              ValidateIssuer = true,
              ValidateAudience = true,
              ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
              ValidIssuer = issuer,
              ValidAudience = issuer,
              IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
          };

          options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
          {
              OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
              {
                  if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                  {
                      context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                  }
                  return Task.CompletedTask;
              }
          };
      });
    }
   ```

   [Note] The JWT Key and Issuer should be same which is used while creating token.
4. Add 'app.UseAuthentication()' in 'Configure' method

   ```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
   ```
5. Add "Authorize" attribute at the header of the Controller or Action method.

   ```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
       ....
    }
   ```

Then, test the application with the JWT token:

[image]

Reference: [ASP.NET Core Web API - Creating And Validating JWT (JSON Web Token)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-web-api-creating-and-validating-jwt-json-web-token/)

Comment: This is good except, I don't have static keys (secrets). Each user get their key dynamically generated (each user has a different key)

Comment: I finally went with this solution which is working great - thank you

Comment: So the token is created by the first API, but the second API can use the same token for authorization given that it knows the secret and issuer, right?