# Is there a simpler way for creating JWTs in ASP.NET core? aka “Best Practices for JWT Authentication?”

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

.NET5 has a ton of middleware and infrastructure for authentication.  You can include a handful of NuGet packages, wire some configuration in Startup.cs, and your application understands cookies and sessions.  All the examples I'm finding online for JWT-based authentication has me manually instantiating a `JwtSecurityDescriptor` and setting properties inside of it.  This really feels like something that should be part of the `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` flow.  Examples would be:

1. https://www.faciletechnolab.com/Blog/2021/4/5/how-to-implement-jwt-token-authentication-in-aspnet-core-50-web-api-using-jwt
2. https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Mar/09/Role-based-JWT-Tokens-in-ASPNET-Core
3. http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/1fdc8b3f-06a1-4f36-8c0b-7852bf850f52.aspx

Am I missing something?  Is this a case where the online examples are skipping several steps in favor of "simplifying" the demonstration?  Every one of the preceding examples creates the JWT manually but delegates a lot of the interpretation of it to the middleware.

To clarify, I am not looking for instruction on how to validate passwords (I do that with `IPasswordHasher`) or locate users (I do that with `IUserPasswordStore`).  I am specifically wondering if there is something I am missing to cause ASP.NET to handle the JWT generation workflow for me.  I can't tell if the online examples are eliding a lot of functionality "for demonstration" or not (similar to how a lot of guides online put DB calls directly inside controllers for "simplicity").

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when we using JWT authentication, the workflow as below:

1. Client sends a request (which contains the user information, such as: name and password) to server for token
2. Server receives the user information and checking for authorization. If validated success, server generates a JWT token.
3. Client receives the token and stores it somewhere locally.
4. Client sends the token in the future requests.
5. Server gets the token from request header, computes Hash again by using a) Header from token b) payload from token c) secret key which server already has.
6. If ("newly computed hash" = "hash came in token"), token is valid otherwise it is tempered or not valid

You could refer to the following steps to use JWT Authentication In ASP.NET Core.

1. Configure the authentication schema with JWT bearer options.

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddJwtBearer(options =>
               {
                   options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {
                       ValidateIssuer = true,
                       ValidateAudience = true,
                       ValidateLifetime = true,
                       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                       ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                       ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                   };
               });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

   }
   ```
2. In this example, I have stored these values in appsettings.json file.

   ```
    {
        "Jwt": {
          "Key": "ThisismySecretKey",
          "Issuer": "Test.com"
        }
    }
   ```
3. Call the app.UseAuthentication() method in the Configure method of startup class.

   ```
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
   ```
4. Generate JSON Web Token

   ```
    using System; 
    using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt; 
    using System.Security.Claims;
    using System.Text; 
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization; 
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
    using Test.Models;

    namespace Test.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class LoginController : ControllerBase
        {
            private IConfiguration _config;

            public LoginController(IConfiguration config)
            {
                _config = config;
            }
            [AllowAnonymous]
            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Login([FromBody] UserModel login)
            {
                IActionResult response = Unauthorized();
                var user = AuthenticateUser(login);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    var tokenString = GenerateJSONWebToken(user);
                    response = Ok(new { token = tokenString });
                }

                return response;
            }

            private string GenerateJSONWebToken(UserModel userInfo)
            {
                var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
                var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userInfo.Username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, userInfo.EmailAddress),
                new Claim("DateOfJoing", userInfo.DateOfJoing.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    claims,
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
                    signingCredentials: credentials);

                return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            }

            private UserModel AuthenticateUser(UserModel login)
            {
                UserModel user = null;

                //Validate the User Credentials    
                //Demo Purpose, I have Passed HardCoded User Information    
                if (login.Username == "Jignesh")
                {
                    user = new UserModel { Username = "Jignesh Trivedi", EmailAddress = "test.btest@gmail.com" };
                }
                return user;
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Then, if you request the "API/login" method to generate the token, you have to passed the following JSON in the request body.

```
{"username": "Jignesh", "password": "password"}
```

Then, after getting the JWT token, you could add the "Authorization" property in the request header when you access other API controller(with the `[Authorize]` attribute).

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJKaWduZXNoIFRyaXZlZGkiLCJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3QuYnRlc3RAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiRGF0ZU9mSm9pbmciOiIwMDAxLTAxLTAxIiwianRpIjoiYzJkNTZjNzQtZTc3Yy00ZmUxLTgyYzAtMzlhYjhmNzFmYzUzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTMyMzU2NjY5LCJpc3MiOiJUZXN0LmNvbSIsImF1ZCI6IlRlc3QuY29tIn0.8hwQ3H9V8mdNYrFZSjbCpWSyR1CNyDYHcGf6GqqCGnY
```

More detail information, refer the followng links:

[JWT Authentication In ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/)

[JWT Validation on separate web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397027/jwt-validation-on-separate-web-api/64425208#64425208)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is very complete and helpful.  However, it still shows the issue I am stuck with.  You are generating the JWT manually inside your controller action.  Is this THE correct place to do it, or is this a demonstration only?  Why is the JWT not being generated inside of some kind of Microsoft.Identity object as part of the SignInManager.SignInAsync workflow?

Comment: This tutorial and the sample are a basic tutorial to tell us how the JWT works and how to use it in our application, you can also create [custom middleware to handle the JWT authentication](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api). Then, if you are using IdentityServer or external provider authentication, the JWT token is generated by the external provider, after getting the token, you could use it according to the above tutorial.