# ASP.NET Core Configure authentication on client web app for an existing token service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, security, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have developed an API that contains an endpoint to get tokens, this acts as the token service and resource server. It uses ASP.NET Identity. All works well, however I would now like to implement a client  Admin web app that will authenticate and call the main secured resource server API, but I struggle to understand how to configure this on a clean web app template. Most examples have an all in one solution where the web app has identity set up and all resource endpoints are in the same project ,whereas I have a separate STS (token service). I am not sure what exactly needs to be added in the Admin Web App, so that it authenticates and authorizes each call.

I have the following added to my Startup file:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
    }).AddCookie();
```

This is the controller endpoint that call the Token Service to retrieve a token:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        var request = new TokenRequest { Email = model.EmailAddress, Password = model.Password };
        var response = await _tokenService.GetTokenAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Error))
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            foreach (var claim in response.Jwt.Claims)
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claim.Type, claim.Value));
            }

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                AllowRefresh = true,
                IsPersistent = true
            };
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), authProperties);
            _logger.LogInformation($"User: {model.EmailAddress} logged in successfully.");

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogError($"User login failed: {model.EmailAddress}");
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, response.Error);
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I first need to configure the auth server (token service) at start up and I would like to pass the current token on each call to the resource server? How can I do that?

Comment: "configure the auth server (token service) at start up" You could refer to this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397027/jwt-validation-on-separate-web-api  and "pass the current token on each call to the resource server" you could refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1107893/secure-api-with-jwt-token-asp-net-core-webapi